# Jquery Отметить чекбоксы на основе параметров URL

Tags: jquery, url, input

Есть форма, в ней подобные чекбоксы:

```
<input form="searchform" type="checkbox" name="rooms[]" value="1">
<input form="searchform" type="checkbox" name="rooms[]" value="2">
<input form="searchform" type="checkbox" name="rooms[]" value="3">
<input form="searchform" type="checkbox" name="rooms[]" value="4">
```

После отправки формы нужно отметить каждый чекбокс, значение которого передано в URL. У меня есть вот такая функция, которая отлично справляется с одиночными чекбоксами, радои-кнопками и всем прочим:

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
            var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
            sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
            sParameterName,
            i;
            for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
                sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
                if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
                    return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
                }
            }
        };
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
            if (getUrlParameter($(this).attr('name')) == $(this).val()) {
                $(this).prop( "checked", true ).trigger( "change" );
            }
        });
```

Но она не обрабатывает те чекбоксы, которые передают массив значений, отмечается только первый из всех элементов. Прошу помочь улучшить эту функцию, либо найти другой способ решения проблемы.

Comment: покажи как выглядит URL

Comment: @АлексейШиманский     `rooms%5B%5D=1&rooms%5B%5D=2&rooms%5B%5D=3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы всевозможные варианты собрать, лучше б сперва собрал все параметры в массив.

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter() {
     var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
                    sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
                    result = {};

     if(!sPageURL) {
          return result;
     }

     for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
         var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');  
         if (!result[sParameterName[0]]) {
             result[sParameterName[0]] = [];
         }
         result[sParameterName[0]].push(sParameterName[1]);
     }
     return result;
};
```

А для проверки, отдельная функция:

```
var checkParam = function(name, value) {
     var params = getUrlParameter();

        if(typeof params[name] == 'undefined') {
            return false;
        }

        if (typeof value == 'undefined')
        {
            return params[name][0];
        }

        if (params[name].indexOf(value) != -1) {
              return true;
        }
        return false;
 }
```

Вот и сама проверка:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
      if (checkParam($(this).attr('name'), $(this).val())) {
             $(this).prop( "checked", true ).trigger( "change" );
      }
});

$('select').each(function() {
     if (val = checkParam($(this).attr('name'))) {
            $(this).val(val);
      }
 });
```

Comment: Отличный ответ и, похоже, все должно работать, но я вижу лишь `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`

Comment: И еще. Старая функция получала значение параметра из url, так она подходила и для инпутов и селектов и всего прочего, то есть можно было проверить и подставить значение из url. Можно ли сделать функцию из вашего ответа такой же? Если нет - омтавлю и новую и старую

Comment: по первому комменту, добавил проверку на наличие параметров

Comment: к сожалению, ничего не изменилось

Comment: @ИванmalginovdesignМальгинов в двух местах поправил, все куски скопировали? у меня ошибки нет

Comment: Да, конечно. Скриншот консоли: http://icecream.me/6bbcf60d2cf7acd01dc976471c729519

Comment: а что в урле? можете скинуть? походу не все предусмотрел

Comment: добавил возможность работы и с другими элементами, только у них 'name' должны быть уникальными, а не массивом

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67432/discussion-between--malginovdesign--and-maxkrasnov).